Blocking bots with apache htaccess
I am trying to block bots (mostly "AI" bots).
I have this in my .htaccess file.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>                                                                              
RewriteEngine on                                                                                      
RewriteBase /                                                                                         
                                                                                                      

# block “AI” bots                                                                                                                                                                                                  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (AdsBot-Google|Amazonbot|anthropic-ai|Applebot|Applebot-Extended|AwarioRssBot|AwarioSmartBot|Bytespider|CCBot|ChatGPT|ChatGPT-User|Claude-Web|ClaudeBot|cohere-ai|DataForSeoBot|Diffbot|FacebookBot|facebookexternalhit|Google-Extended|GPTBot|ImagesiftBot|magpie-rawler|omgili|Omgilibot|peer39_crawler|PerplexityBot|YouBot|AhrefsBot|Barkrowler|SemrushBot|DotBot) [NC] 
                                                                                                             
RewriteRule ^ – [F]                                                                                   
</IfModule>                                                                                           
                     

It seems to works for most bots but I have still some connection for several of them.
For example:
185.191.171.7 - - [17/Jul/2024:11:27:12 +0200] "GET my/website/url HTTP/1.1" 200 14234 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/7~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"

I do not understand why this connection is going through apache while "SemrushBot" is inside the blocking list. Why is that and how can I improve the blocking?
